# Implementing pipelining in c. What would be the best way to do that? (Own shell in linux)

Tags: c, linux, pipeline

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Implementing pipelining in c. What would be the best way to do that? (Own linux shell)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13331139/implementing-pipelining-in-c-what-would-be-the-best-way-to-do-that-own-linux)

I can't think of any way to implement pipelining in c that would actually work. That's why I've decided to write in here. I have to say, that I understand how do pipe/fork/mkfifo work. I've seen plenty examples of implementing 2-3 pipelines. It's easy. My problem starts, when I've got to implement shell, and pipelines count is unknown.

What I've got now:
eg.

```
ls -al | tr a-z A-Z | tr A-Z a-z | tr a-z A-Z
```

I transform such line into something like that:

```
array[0] = {"ls", "-al", NULL"}
array[1] = {"tr", "a-z", "A-Z", NULL"}
array[2] = {"tr", "A-Z", "a-z", NULL"}
array[3] = {"tr", "a-z", "A-Z", NULL"}
```

So I can use

```
execvp(array[0],array)
```

later on.

Untli now, I believe everything is OK. Problem starts, when I'm trying to redirect those functions input/output to eachother.

My executing commands part is working like that:

```
-change stdin to pipes_in
-change stdout to pipes_out
-exec(array[i], array)
```

For some reason, It doesnt work.
Here's how I'm doing that:

```
    mkfifo("queue", 0777);

    for (i = 0; i<= pipelines_count; i++) // eg. if there's 3 pipelines, there's 4 functions to execvp
    {
    int b = fork();             
    if (b == 0) // child
        {           
        int c = fork();

        if (c == 0) 
        // baby (younger than child) 
        // I use c process, to unblock desc_read and desc_writ for b process only
        // nothing executes in here
            {       
            if (i == 0) // 1st pipeline
                {
                int desc_read = open("queue", O_RDONLY);
                // dup2 here, so after closing there's still something that can read from 
                // from desc_read
                dup2(desc_read, 0); 
                close(desc_read);           
                }

            if (i == pipelines_count) // last pipeline
                {
                int desc_write = open("queue", O_WRONLY);
                dup2(desc_write, 0);
                close(desc_write);                              
                }

            if (i > 0 && i < pipelines_count) // pipeline somewhere inside
                {
                int desc_read = open("queue", O_RDONLY);
                int desc_write = open("queue", O_WRONLY);
                dup2(desc_write, 1);
                dup2(desc_read, 0);
                close(desc_write);
                close(desc_read);
                }               
            exit(0); // closing every connection between process c and pipeline             
            }
        else
        // b process here
        // in b process, i execvp commands
        {                       
        if (i == 0) // 1st pipeline (changing stdout only)
            {   
            int desc_write = open("queue", O_WRONLY);               
            dup2(desc_write, 1); // changing stdout -> pdesc[1]
            close(desc_write);                  
            }

        if (i == pipelines_count) // last pipeline (changing stdin only)
            {   
            int desc_read = open("queue", O_RDONLY);                                    
            dup2(desc_read, 0); // changing stdin -> pdesc[0]   
            close(desc_read);           
            }

        if (i > 0 && i < pipelines_count) // pipeline somewhere inside
            {               
            int desc_write = open("queue", O_WRONLY);       
            dup2(desc_write, 1); // changing stdout -> pdesc[1]
            int desc_read = open("queue", O_RDONLY);                            
            dup2(desc_read, 0); // changing stdin -> pdesc[0]
            close(desc_write);
            close(desc_read);                               
            }

        wait(NULL); // it wait's until, process c is death                      
        execvp(array[0],array);         
        }
        }
    else // parent (waits for 1 sub command to be finished)
        {       
        wait(NULL);
        }       
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Hmm... last year, everyone was printing geometric shapes with asterisks, and this year everyone and their dog are making their own shells. The gods of CS move in mysterious ways...

Comment: I didn't think you would need to make a fifo in the file system for this. Wouldn't pipe, fork and dup suffice?

Comment: You could study the source of small free shells like `sash`, or `strace` your favorite shell.

Comment: -1 for posting the same question twice. A user with 400+ rep should know that's against the etiquette.